# Algorithm to take chunks from a large number until the chunks sum to the original large number

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to write an algorithm/code(in java) to take chunks(randomly) from a large number and sum the chunks up to the original large number. And, the number of chunk should be dynamic.
Example:
Suppose, the large number(LN) is 300000.
The algorithm need smaller-chunks(SC) that should be random such as 80K,80K,40K,100K (basically in Ks-not greater than 100k) that would sum up to be the LN(300000).
The number of chunks should be dependent upon the user input.

Below is th code I have right now:

```
AverageChunk=LargeNumber/NumberOfChunks;
LowerLimit = AverageChunk/1000 - 11;
UpperLimit = AverageChunk/1000 + 11;
n=1,chunkUntilNow=0,nextChunkIncrement=0,
nextChunkDecrement=0;nextFiveChunkDecrement=0;
totalChunkUntilNow = 0;cnt=0;
while(n<=NumberOfChunks){
    cnt++;
    chunk=random(LowerLimit to UpperLimit)*1000;
    takeChunk = chunk + nextChunkIncrement - nextFiveChunkDecrement;
    if(chunk < nextFiveChunkDecrement){  //CASE FLUCTUATE
        if((nextFiveChunkDecrement-chunk)>chunk){
            takeChunk = nextFiveChunkDecrement-chunk;
        }
    }    
    totalChunkUntilNow = totalChunkUntilNow + takeChunk;
    if(n%10 ==5){
        if(totalChunkUntilNow<AverageChunk){
            nextChunkIncrement = AverageChunk*cnt - totalChunkUntilNow;
            nextChunkDecrement = 0;
        }else{
            nextChunkDecrement = totalChunkUntilNow - AverageChunk*cnt;
            nextFiveChunkDecrement = nextChunkDecrement /5;
        }
    }
}
```

This current code takes a largeNumber and divides it by the numberOfRequiredChunks and find the averageChunkPerExtraction. The averageChunkPerExtraction is divided by 1000 and then added/substracted by 11 to get the upperLimit/lowerLimit. A random number is then generated between the limits and multiplied by 1000 to get a random chunk for extraction.......

but this code generates error with increasing/decreasing upper/lower limit and fluctuating error depending upon the number of times it enters the CASE FLUCTUATE

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP has already mentioned that chunk should be dynamic

Comment: The large number is dynamic.
The smaller chunks should be randomly generated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free homework completion service. Show us some code and we'll recommend changes in that.

Comment: @Bomzan your condition is not clear for the number of  chunks.

Comment: @Lokesh The chunks, by which I mean the small numbers that need to be added to make up the large number, should be randomly generated.

Comment: The variables aren't typed. There is no debugging output. There is no return value. There is no main-method to see, how this code is setup and to help testing it. How do you test it? You don't stick to coding conventions (variable names lower case). Everything is a big mess. Make your idea clear and let the code represent it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty way.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ChunkChunk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: ChunkChunk [Long Number] [number of chunks]");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        Random randGen = new Random();
        int startNum = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int numChunks = randGen.nextInt(startNum/1000);
        int endNum = 0; 

        if (args.length == 2) {
           int arg2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
           if (startNum % arg2 > 0) {
               System.out.println("Number of Chunks must be a distribution of 1k in large number");
               System.exit(0);
           } 
           numChunks = arg2;
        }

        System.out.println("Starting: " + startNum + "\tNumber of Chunks: " + numChunks);
        int startSeed = (startNum/numChunks);
        int index = 0;
        while(startNum > 0) {
            startSeed = (startNum/numChunks) >= 1000 ? startSeed : 1000; 
            int chunk = randGen.nextInt(startSeed) + 1;  
            chunk = (chunk / 1000) * 1000;
            if (chunk > 0) {
                if (numChunks == 1) {
                    endNum += startNum;
                    startNum = 0;
                } else {
                    startNum -= chunk;
                    endNum += chunk;
                }
                System.out.println(String.format("%d. Remaing: %d\t\tChunk: %d\t\t End: %d", ++index, startNum, chunk, endNum));
                numChunks--;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

---

```
[Running] cd "/Users/raymonddoran/Development/TDF/StackOverflow/" && javac ChunkChunk.java && java ChunkChunk
Starting: 300000        Number of Chunks: 10
1. Remaing: 281000              Chunk: 19000             End: 19000
2. Remaing: 261000              Chunk: 20000             End: 39000
3. Remaing: 249000              Chunk: 12000             End: 51000
4. Remaing: 246000              Chunk: 3000              End: 54000
5. Remaing: 220000              Chunk: 26000             End: 80000
6. Remaing: 217000              Chunk: 3000              End: 83000
7. Remaing: 205000              Chunk: 12000             End: 95000
8. Remaing: 176000              Chunk: 29000             End: 124000
9. Remaing: 173000              Chunk: 3000              End: 127000
10. Remaing: 0          Chunk: 27000             End: 300000
Done
```

Comment: Thanks @Raymond but this code generates high valued chunks initially(408284) and slowly decreases to 2. What I wanted to do is to generate chunks that would be random below 100K mark and in K-form (20K,24K). Also the number of chunks should be dependent on the user's input

Answer (score 0):

So for instance, you have 300000 elements, and 4 as number of Chunks. Every size will be in average 300k/4 = 75k. Bad decision! Start with an easy case, 4 chunks, 400.000.

Most simple case: One chunk, size  400.000. How do you represent this chunk? How do you represent 4 chunks? 
Did you ever hear about collections, like Lists, Vector, Arrays?

One chunk:

```
List<Integer> chunks = new List <> ();
chunks.add (400);
```

4 Chunks:

```
List<Integer> chunks = new List <> ();
chunks.add (100);
chunks.add (100);
chunks.add (100);
chunks.add (100);
```

4 Chunks with variation:

```
List<Integer> chunks = new List <> ();
chunks.add (150); 
chunks.add (120);
chunks.add ( 80);
chunks.add ( 50);
```

5 parameterized Chunks on size:

```
List<Integer> getChunks (int size, int chunkcount) {
    List<Integer> chunks = new List <> ();
    avgsize = size / chunkcount;
    chunks.add (150*avgsize/100); 
    chunks.add (120*avgsize/100);
    chunks.add ( 80*avgsize/100);
    chunks.add ( 50*avgsize/100);
    return chunks;
}
```

Random chunks: Do it later.

Divide your code into independent, small modules, which can easily be testet.

A List of chunks is something, which is easy to pass to a method, and it is easy to return it from a method.

Write your program with the simple List, for easy testing. Make a stub which is as soon as possible runnable. A hello-world - thingy, which prints it's name. You need to test often, every new step.